# Having issue trying to retrieve data from Website to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, finance, stock

I want to retrieve a number from the stock website TipRanks, specifically how much upside the stock has according to analyst. It is a simple number to grab and place in a cell range. First off, I am not familiar with coding in VBA at all. I found some video that explains how to retrieve data from a website and used that code. I edited the code where it was needed. Here is my sample code:

```
Sub StockRetrieve()

Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome"

For i = 3 To 16
  link = Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
  bot.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", link
  bot.SwitchToNextWindow
  upside = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='tr-stock-page- 
  content']/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div").Text
  Sheets(1).Range("G" & i).Value = upside
Next i
MsgBox "good"
```

Basically the code is suppose to read through a list of URLs on my spreadsheet and open those urls up in new tabs. It then finds the upside percentage put them in column G rows 3 to 16.

The error message that i just got was: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Innaccessible logs: security

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What Excel are you using and what is the WebDriver object you are referencing? What line is the error on?

Comment: actually i fixed the error but now the new error occurs with finding the Xpath. It tells me that element is not found. Im trying to find the upside potential that you can get from TipRanks